# Python: suppressing the unsolicited console output

Tags: python, console, output

I've got an application creating some console output. It also uses a third party library, which happens to create some visual spam:

```
25/25   /home/alexey/dir-dst/dir-src1/0025-12 Byzantine Rulers_ Part 17 - Conclusion.mp3
24/25   /home/alexey/dir-dst/dir-src1/0024-12 Byzantine Rulers_ Part 16 - Constantine XI.mp3
 /home/alexey/spaces/python/py-procr/procr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mutagen/id3/_frames.py:137: ID3Warning: Leftover data: WFED: b'http://www.anders.com/lectures/lars_brownworth/12_byzantine_rulers/rss.xml\x00' (from b'\x00http://www.anders.com/lectures/lars_brownworth/12_byzantine_rulers/rss.xml\x00')
ID3Warning)
23/25   /home/alexey/dir-dst/dir-src1/0023-12 Byzantine Rulers_ Part 15 - Isaac.mp3
22/25   /home/alexey/dir-dst/dir-src1/0022-12 Byzantine Rulers_ Part 14 - Alexius.mp3
21/25   /home/alexey/dir-dst/dir-src1/0021-12 Byzantine Rulers_ Part 13 - Basil II.mp3
```

The output between lines 24 and 23 is not mine. Is there a way to get rid of it short of tampering with the library's source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are seeing is a warning.  You can use the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html), in particular [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) to suppress printing of warnings based on a variety of filter criteria.

There is no generally applicable way to suppress output of a third-party library.

Comment: Thank you very much, **Sven**! As simple as that:        warnings.resetwarnings()
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')